# Extracting date from an HTML Class and return the difference to another date into a text box (days)

Tags: javascript, html, automation, tampermonkey

I'm a newbie on all programming
languages, but I'm getting addicted
:-) .
I'm trying to extract from an HTML Page
two different dates and make
the difference in days, returning the
value on a text-box (on the same
page) creating Tampermonkey script.
First date is under:

```
<dl class="dates">
  <dt>Change Planned Date:</dt>
  <dd class="date type-datetime">
    <span
      data-name="Change Planned Date"
      id="customfield_10107-val"
      data-fieldtype="datetime"
      data-fieldtypecompletekey="com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:datetime"
      class="editable-field inactive"
      title="Click to edit">
      <span
        title="06/Jun/20 8:00 AM"><time
          class="livestamp allow-future"
          datetime="2020-06-06T08:00:00+0200">06/Jun/20
          8:00
          AM</time></span>
      <span
        class="overlay-icon aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-edit"></span></span>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

And it is the **06/Jun/20**

The second date is under

```
<div class="issue-data-block"
  id="changehistory-33159">
  <div class="actionContainer">
    <div class="action-details"
      id="changehistorydetails_33159">
      <a class="user-hover user-avatar"
        rel="raffaele.franceschi"
        id="changehistoryauthor_33159"
        href="/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=raffaele.franceschi"><span
          class="aui-avatar aui-avatar-xsmall"><span
            class="aui-avatar-inner"><img
              src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5fed0615dc1dfbae21ad0dd93e789fd9?d=mm&amp;s=16"
              alt="raffaele.franceschi"></span></span>
        Raffaele
        Franceschi</a>
      made changes - <span class="date"
        title="11/May/20 11:06 AM"><time
          class="livestamp"
          datetime="2020-05-11T11:06:53+0200">11/May/20
          11:06
          AM</time></span>
    </div>
    <div
      class="changehistory action-body">
      <table cellpadding="0"
        cellspacing="0" border="0"
        width="100%"
        id="changehistory_33159">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td width="20%"
              class="activity-name">
              Status
            </td>
            <td width="40%"
              class="activity-old-val">
              Open
              <span class="hist-value">[
                1
                ]</span>
            </td>
            <td width="40%"
              class="activity-new-val">
              Awaiting FM/HSM Approval
              <span class="hist-value">[
                10107
                ]</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And it is the **11/May/20**

I would like to have the number of day between the planned and the approval state so from 11 May to 06 June = 26 Days on my text box.

Do you think is feasible? I read here about the use of datediff in
Java, but I honestly do not know how to read first the right values on my HTML and then to output it on a tampermonkey textbox.
**An ALL-IN solution would it be possible?** Any suggestion/advice is appreciated (on type of commands or different ways to approach, better simple ones), then I'll try to squeeze as much as I can my brain in order to progress.

Many thanks in advance!
F.

Comment: Firs at all, HI Everyone!

Comment: Try to indent your code properly so that your code becomes more readable to others

Comment: Hi Vishist, thanks for your quick reply! I have performed the action you requested and thanks for using technical language (indent), so I learnt another little piece on programming, now it's also easier for me to read it. when I created the post I copied the code directly from "inspect on Chrome" thinking it was the proper way!

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("time")` can return a list of <time> elements which have the date information you need.